# firefox vs chrome jquery select

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have 2 `select`. The first select is required. The second select is required with condition `display: none` and `disabled`.

If the user selects `rev` from the first select, it will hide the second select.
If the user selects `approve` from the first select, it will show the second select and remove the `disabled` attribute.

It works fine in firefox, but when I try in Chrome it fails. What's wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('work di firefox, chrome gagal');
  $("#netral").on("click", function() {
    $("#target1").show();
    $("#target2").addAttr("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#revisi").on("click", function() {
    $("#target1").hide();
  });
  $("#approve").on("click", function() {
    $("#target1").show();
    $("#target2").removeAttr("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

select:hover {
  border: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Select 1
    <select name="status" id="status" required>
      <option value="" id="netral"> - </option>
      <option value="1" id="rev"> Rev </option>
      <option value="3" id="approve"> Approve </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="target1">
    Select 2
    <select class="form-control" name="data" id="target2" disabled required>
      <option value=""> - </option>
      <option value="1">Supl 1</option>
      <option value="2">Supl 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some console.logs/breakpoints in each of your event handlers - they never fire in chrome.  Use `$("select").on("change", function() { $(this).val() ...` rather than `<option id=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching `click` event handlers to the `option` elements directly, which is not well supported.

A better way is to add a `change` event handler to the `select` and check its `value` at that point. Then you can hide/show and enable/disable all relevant elements from there. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $target1 = $('#target1');
  let $target2 = $('#target2');
  
  $('#status').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value === '' || value === '3') {
      $target1.show();
      $target2.prop("disabled", false);
    } else if (value === '1') {
      $target1.hide()
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

select:hover {
  border: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Select 1
    <select name="status" id="status" required>
      <option value=""> - </option>
      <option value="1" id="rev"> Rev </option>
      <option value="3" id="approve"> Approve </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="target1">
    Select 2
    <select class="form-control" name="data" id="target2" disabled required>
      <option value=""> - </option>
      <option value="1">Supl 1</option>
      <option value="2">Supl 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Rory McCrossan.
It's works!

once again ,thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $target1 = $('#target1');
  let $target2 = $('#target2');
  
  $('#status').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value === '' || value === '3') {
      $target1.show();
      $target2.prop("disabled", false);
    } else if (value === '1') {
      $target1.hide()
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

select:hover {
  border: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Select 1
    <select name="status" id="status" required>
      <option value=""> - </option>
      <option value="1" id="rev"> Rev </option>
      <option value="3" id="approve"> Approve </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="target1">
    Select 2
    <select class="form-control" name="data" id="target2" disabled required>
      <option value=""> - </option>
      <option value="1">Supl 1</option>
      <option value="2">Supl 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```